# iOS app crashes when loading an image

Tags: ios, swift, crash, imageview

Goals:

1. Programmatically load first image (approx 94kb) into an ImageView in the main storyboard from the Assets.xcassets folder (see code below) - works perfect
2. Then when you load a second image (same size) into the original UIImage it causes the iOS app to crash.

Here is my code:

> ```
> mainImageView.image = UIImage(named:"FirstImage.png") // load first image, no issues
> ```

Then if you programmatically load a second image into the same UIImage it causes the device to throw a low memory warning and the iOS crashes the app:

> ```
> mainImageView.image = UIImage(named:"SecondImage.png") // load second image
> ```

Comment: Please show us the stack trace.

Comment: Show more code around second image loading. The error should be somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a number of answers on SO and other articles (see below), the best way to manage memory when you are loading multiple images into an animation array is to use the `contentsOfFile: imageName` instead of the `UIImage(named:"FirstImage.png")`

See Article here:

http://www.alexcurylo.com/2009/01/13/imagenamed-is-evil/

And secondly Apple states the following:

> If a matching image object is not
>   already in the cache, this method locates and loads the image data
>   from disk or from an available asset catalog, and then returns the
>   resulting object. The system may purge cached image data at any time
>   to free up memory. Purging occurs only for images that are in the
>   cache but are not currently being used. In iOS 9 and later, this
>   method is thread safe. Special Considerations If you have an image
>   file that will only be displayed once and wish to ensure that it does
>   not get added to the system’s cache, you should instead create your
>   image using **imageWithContentsOfFile:**. This will keep your single-use
>   image out of the system image cache, potentially improving the memory
>   use characteristics of your app.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624146-init

Lastly, upon receiving the Memory Warning you could also create the following function:

```
func applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning(application: UIApplication) {
        NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
    }
```

Hope this helps someone else :)